# Silverstripe 2.4 access db var from other page

Tags: silverstripe

On Startpage.php:

```
class StartPage extends Page {

    public static $db = array(
        'Sperrtag' => 'Varchar'
    );

function example(){

.........
$test = $this->Sperrtag;
.........

}
```

how can i access $this->Sperrtag from another page?

Tryed StartPage::$db->Sperrtag

and a lot of other variants

no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access an instance of `StartPage` instead of the class itself.
most probably you have only 1 'StartPage', so you could write **in silverstripe 3**:

```
$sperrtag = StartPage::get()->First()->Sperrtag;
```

for silverstripe 2.4 it's:

```
$startpage = DataObject::get_one('Startpage');
$sperrtag = $startpage->Sperrtag;
```

you should have a look at http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel to get an understanding of silverstripe's data handling.